# how to put the result in multiple variables using for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas

how to put the result in multiple variables using for loop in python?

example,

```
initial_data = {'First_name': ['Ram', 'Mohan', 'Tina', 'Jeetu', 'Meera'],  
                'Last_name': ['Kumar', 'Sharma', 'Ali', 'Gandhi', 'Kumari'],  
                'Test': ['fail','pass','fail','pass','fail'] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(initial_data, columns = ['First_name', 'Last_name', 'Test']) 


for i in range(4): 
    a = df.iloc[:df.Test.str.contains('pass',na=False).idxmax()]

    for j in range(1,3):    
        globals()['val_{}'.format(j)] = a
        a = pd.concat([df, a]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

I want my result look like,

output:

val_1

```
First_name  Last_name   Test
0   Ram Kumar    fail
```

val_2

```
First_name  Last_name   Test
2   Tina    Ali     fail
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Constructing variables dynamically can certainly be done but it's rarely a good idea. Much better to use a dictionary or perhaps another dataframe

Comment: Yeah... unsure why you don't just want a DF with two rows in it preserving the original index? Something like `df.head(4).query('Test == "fail"')` will give you perfectly usable output.

Comment: Thanks Jon, 
actually, my ideal result is to have dataframe untill 'pass' comes , and when first row is removed of the whole dataframe, then second row might get 'fail' which I also want to split. That is why I use for loop.

Can you give me some more advice?

Answer (score 0):

Using `query`, as was suggested in the comments:

```
for i in range(0, len(df.query('Test == "fail"'))):
    globals()["var_"+str(i+1)] = df.query('Test == "fail"').iloc[i].to_frame().T
```

This loops through all those that are "fail", and creates a new dataframe for each row.

Not really sure what you are planning to do with this afterwards, separating them all doesn't make it easy to analyse.

If you actually wanted to group blocks of "fails" together (which I didn't take to be the case from the question, but could possible be interpreted from your last comment):

```
splits = [-1] + list(df.query('Test == "pass"').index) + [len(df)]

for i in range(1, len(splits)):
    globals()["var_"+str(i)] = df.iloc[splits[i-1]+1: splits[i]]
```